# ¿Cómo puedo separar una string por espacio pero sólo mostrar lo que está después del mismo?

Tags: c++

tengo una string con nombre y apellido (en ese orden) pero sólo necesito guardar el apellido en otra variable.
Tengo este código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data {
    string nombre_apellido;
    int codigo;
    string sector;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    
    Data d = {"juan romero", 34256543, "planta"};
    char separador = ' ';
    string sentencia = d.nombre_apellido;
    for(size_t p=0, q=0; p!=sentencia.npos; p=q) {
        cout << sentencia.substr(p+(p!=0),(q=sentencia.find(separador, p+1))-p-(p!=0))<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Podrían decirme cómo podría guardar sólo el apellido en otra variable?

Comment: sólo como comentario, no sería mejor obtenerlos de campos separados directamente? es decir, que pasa si se llama "Juan Pablo Romero"?

Comment: En la consigna que me dieron sobre este ejercicio pide directamente que nombre y apellido estén dentro de una misma variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar find para encontrar el espacio, y substr para recortar el string.
El código quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data {
    string nombre_apellido;
    int codigo;
    string sector;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    
    Data d = {"juan romero", 34256543, "planta"};
    char separador = ' ';
    string sentencia = d.nombre_apellido;
    string apellido = sentencia.substr(sentencia.find(separador) + 1);
    cout << apellido;
    
    return 0;
}
```

También puedes probarlo en linea aquí: http://cpp.sh/3rajt.
Suerte!